# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'. in my flutter app

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin

my flutter app showing error

```
 What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
   > Duplicate class com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture found in modules jetified-guava-20.0 (com.google.guava:guava:20.0) and jetified-listenablefuture-1.0 (com.google.guava:listenablefuture:1.0)
```

first show this error i create new project & shift my lib & assets & pubspec  in new project then again build failed! new error comes

```
Module was compiled with an incompatible version of Kotlin. The binary version of its metadata is 1.5.1, expected version is 1.1.15.
```

i found solution of that

```
what solved my problem is changing this at build.gradle
from
ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.50'
to
ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
or what ever the latest version of Kotlin available and make sure to update Kotlin version on Android Studio as well
```

then again come old one error in new project .
***Note***
i am using without null safety version because some plugins that i used not support

***EDIT***

```
***Build.gradle***
buildscript {
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.4.32'
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.10'
        // classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

***Gradle.properties***

```
#Fri Jun 23 08:50:38 CEST 2017
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip
```

***Pubspec***

```
  auto_size_text_pk: any
  bot_toast: ^4.0.1
  carousel_slider: any
  clipboard: ^0.1.3
  cloudinary_public: ^0.9.0
  cupertino_icons: any
  dh_slider: any
  # facebook_audience_network: any
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.0
  firebase_core: any
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.9.2
  flutter_pollfish: ^4.0.1
  flutter_spinning_wheel: any
  font_awesome_flutter: ^9.1.0
  form_field_validator: ^1.0.1
  google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.2+1
  google_sign_in: any
  http: any
  image_picker: any
  is_app_installed: any
  page_transition: any
  provider: any
  rxdart: any
  shared_preferences: any
  url_launcher: any
```

Comment: Can you post your `build.gradle` and `gradle.properties` files

Comment: @Nitish i update it please check it

Comment: Did you add any new library in your pubspec.yaml file?  Check for any duplicate under  dependencies. for example : you may be use barcode scanner and image picker in the same project. barcod scanner has a image picker inside it. so a problem will be occured as this.

Comment: @Nitish check my pubspec

Comment: Can you try removing `http` from the pubspec.yaml [cloudinary_public](https://github.com/djade007/cloudinary_public/blob/master/pubspec.yaml) already seems to have that present inside it

Comment: @Nitish i remove   google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.2+1 plugin my app working fine no error in during build . but i need to used   google_mobile_ads for monetizing my app with FAN Bidding

Comment: `google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.5` try using the latest version , also make sure you have  added `meta-data` inside your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @Nitish google_mobile_ads & google_sign_in not working together i remove google_sign_in and used google_sign_in_mocks but still same error when i remove google sign option from app everything working fine

Comment: What's the version of dart you are using, and also the `google_mobile_ads` and `google_sign_in` versions

Comment: I tested at my end using all the latest version and app seems to compile at my end `Flutter version 2.5.1` , `Dart version 2.14.2` , `environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"` , `  google_sign_in: ^5.1.1` and `google_mobile_ads: ^0.13.5`

Comment: @Nitish my every thing is same but environment:   sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0" is this because some plugins that is used not support null safety

Comment: Sorry man, I have no further suggestions of what could be the cause of this, neither I can test this in my add as reducing it causes many null safety error in my project., to keep me updated also if you kind any solution